# How to copy file from PC to android tablet?

Tags: usb, file-transfer

When I connect the android tablet to windows 7 I get 2 external devices, one of them (H) doesn't open.
[image]

When I open G:, I get this

[image]

If I want to copy an app (adobe reader) to the tablet, to which folder should I copy it?

This is the screen of the tablet:

[image]

Where should I access the folders and files from?

Comment: You could try moving the .apk to the Download folder and opening the Downloads app to see if it shows up. To access the files and folders from the tablet you will need a file browser.

Comment: @TheDoorkeeper Where can I get a file browser from? (**note:** I don't have a wifi).

Comment: Sorry, the only place I know is Google Play. How did you get the Adobe Reader, wired internet? I'll try to find one you can download as soon as I can.

Comment: Without internet, and (as it looks like) only USB connection, you might want to take a look into ADB. Then you could simply invoke `adb install myfile.apk` to get the app installed. For how to install ADB, see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

Comment: [Here](http://download.cnet.com/Android-File-Browser/3000-2248_4-10976842.html) is a file explorer you can download with your computer and transfer to your tablet. I haven't tested it as my tablet isn't working, but it is from Cnet and ranked #4. Hope it helps! @Izzy's idea is also good.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Android Development Kit (See Bottom) then there is a super easy way to install an application from a file. All you need to do is start up a Terminal and type:

```
adb install -r <your.apk>
```

the `-r` function will replace an existing application with the same name.

No fumbling around with SD cards and no searching your phone for transfered files. If you are an avid Android user then I recommend getting the ADK.

[How to install just ADK Binaries](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb)

Comment: It's not necessary to install the entire SDK for that (see my comments on the question itself). For a more minimalistic approach (just copying a few files to have a working ADB), take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

Answer (score 1):

You can download ES File Manager from Google Play Store. Here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

Answer (score 0):

just download adobe reader from Google Play store to get the correct version.  if you want to copy over PDF files.  just create your own directory under g:\Download and copy to the mapped drive on your PC.  Make sure you turn on allow to be used as a USB Drive.